# Async pymongo error "attached to a different loop"

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, python-asyncio

I am  getting this Runtime error "attached to a different loop"
Edit: I am already using the async motor driver

**dBase.py**
used for interacting with database this has a function

```
async def getChatids():
      data = list()
      async for document in Collection.find({}, {'chatid':1, '_id':0}):
              data.append(document['chatid'])
      return data
```

The above function works well while testing in dBase.py using this code below

```
async def main():
     ids = await getChatids()
     print(ids)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

While running it in **main.py** or **bot.py** (telegram bot using aiogram)

**main.py**
main running code

```
async def main():
     await asyncio.gather(
          bot.dp.start_polling(),
          scan() #function to scan api 
          )
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

The scan function calls this fuction below

```
async def parseData(data):
        if(some conditon related to data):
           await bot.broadcast("hello broacasting")
```

**broadcast function**

```
async def broadcast(data):  
ids = await getChatids() 
for id in ids:
    await bot.send_message(id,data)
```

After trying a lot I am unable to get whats the problem is. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this line of code below
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
was causing the problem.